# TSQL Finding duplicates

Tags: sql-server-2005

Finding Duplicate Row with Count Numbers

Suppose a table is given

```
  ID  Name      Age
  ----------------- 
  1   Jon       30
  2   Skeet     30 
  1   Jon       30
  4   Gravell   30
  5   NULL      30 
  4   Gravell   30
  5   NULL      30 
  7   James     40
```

Required output (NULL also should comparable)

```
  ID  Name      Age  Description
  -----------------  -----------
  1   Jon       30      Found 1
  1   Jon       30      Found 2
  4   Gravell   30      Found 1
  4   Gravell   30      Found 2
  5   NULL      30      Found 1
  5   NULL      30      Found 2
  7   James     40      Found 1
  2   Skeet     30      Found 1
```

For finding duplicates I can execute the query

```
select ID,Name,Age from tableA  group by ID,Name,Age having count(*) >1
```

How to generate the description?

Comment: not sure i understand. How can you have 1 - Jon - 30 - Found 1, and then 1 Jon - 30 - Found 2. Shouldnt 1 - Jon - 30 - Found 2 be the only record (as its a count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ID, Name, Age,
    'Found ' + CAST(ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) AS varchar(10)) AS Description
FROM
    MyTable
ORDER BY
    ID, Description
```

Your desired output order is essentially random at the ID/Name level

To find duplicates...

```
SELECT
    ID, Name, Age, 'Found ' + Countof AS Description
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ID, Name, Age,
        CAST(ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) AS varchar(10)) AS Countof
    FROM
        MyTable
    ) foo
WHERE
    Countof > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
select ID,Name,Age, ('Found ' +  cast(count(*) as varchar(5))) as description
from tableA  group by ID,Name,Age having count(*) >1
```